# RHC SSH error for openshift : No supported authentication methods available

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, openshift

I have already generated an SSH key using Puttygen, and I still am still getting this error. Anyone knows how to fix this? Please help thank you!

```
C:\>rhc ssh -a ay1617
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Connecting to 576d560c89f5cf169800006b@ay1617-mariah.rhcloud.com ...
Using username "576d560c89f5cf169800006b".
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puttygen uses a different key type than OpenSSH. Look at these instructions I wrote for using FileZilla (which also uses puttygen) and it may help

https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/

Comment: Hi, I used FileZilla as well, and it comes out with the same problem.